# How to count number of rows excluding rows with duplicate data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table in which the column "Doc. No." has duplicate info as below; please advise on which formula I should use to count the number of unique Doc. that I have (as reference to the below table extraction for instance; at one glance we are able to determine that the number of Doc. is four, i.e. `21571`, `27868`, `25016` & `21574`).

However, my table has thousands of rows; therefore, doing this by eye is not feasible. Please teach me how to create the formula. By the way, I’m currently using Microsoft Excel 2010.

```
ROW No.   DOC. No.   DESCRIPTION
1         21571      COVERALL , RED SIZE : S
2         21571      COVERALL , RED SIZE : M
3         21571      COVERALL , RED SIZE : L
4         21571      COVERALL , RED SIZE : XL
5         27868      HOLLOW 4"X4"X6MMX6MTR
6         27868      HOLLOW 3"X3"X6MMX6MTR
7         27868      HOLLOW 2"X2"X61.6MMX6MTR
8         25016      DUCORIT/1000KG PER BAG
9         25016      DUCORIT/300KG PER BAG
10        21574      HW-045133, 4"X1/4"X5/8" 4" GRINC
12        21574      HW-055238, 5"X1/8"X7/8"5" GRINDING DISC
```

Comment: does this help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply just make a pivot table and put Doc in row label that will saw you all the unique numbers in doc column. Then simply just mark them and see the count or use the count formula

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to select your DOC. No. column and use Data > Sort & Filter - Advanced with Copy to another location checked, a suitable (Row1) Copy to: selected and Unique records only checked. The last but one row number of the list should be the count of uniques.